# Trouble using mpir_ui type in my code

Tags: c++, windows, mpir

I wanted to use this function

```
int mpz_cmp_ui (mpz t_op1, mpir_ui op2)
```

For that I have to supply mpir_ui

so whenever I try to declare this ,

```
 mpir_ui myui;
```

it says:

```
 Error: identifier mpir_ui is undefined
```

Am I missing any header file?

All other types and functions work , but only this one is failing.

**These are my header file**

```
#include < cstdio>
#include < stdlib.h>
#include < stdio.h>
#include < gmpxx.h>
#include < iostream>
#include <mpirxx.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mpir.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string>
```

Comment: Why are you including mpirxx.h?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `mpir.h`. When you use `mpz_cmp_ui` or `mpir_ui`, you need to `#include mpir.h` to get their definitions.

Comment: I am having this header file. Still Intelisense keep complaining.