# Why I get "mpir_ui" was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, gmp, mpfr, mpir

after installing mpir-3.0 on fedora 31. Now I try to build project:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpir.h>
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

     mpf_t a;         //mpir float variable
     mpf_init(a);     //initialise a
     mpir_ui two = 2; //mpir unsigned integer variable
     FILE* stream;    //file type pointer to output on standard output (console)
     mpf_init_set_ui (a, 2);          //set value of a to 2
     mpf_out_str (stream, 10, 2, a); //output value of a
     cout << "\nMPIR working" << "\n" ;

}
```

But when I compile it I get this error:

```
‘mpir_ui’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘mpfr_ai’?|
```

I've used the flags:

```
 -lmpir -lmpfr -lgmp
```

Comment: where are your includes? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644716/trouble-using-mpir-ui-type-in-my-code

Comment: Do you have `#include "mpir.h"` in your code?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes I've already. I've edited the code.

Comment: @idclev463035818: Edited.

Comment: You might compile with `-v` to see what include directories are being searched, and if you're getting the version of `mpir.h` that you think you are.  You could also look at the preprocessor output (use `-E`) and see if the typedef of `mpir_ui` is there.

Comment: By the way, your code isn't going to work unless you initialize `stream` to something (perhaps `stdout`?).

Comment: Why include both gmp.h and mpir.h?